# Compiler error recursion linked list

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list, nodes

```
int insert(node* head) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        node* temp = new node;
        if (head == NULL) {
            cout << "Error";
            return 0;
        }
        temp->data = 20;
        temp->next = NULL;
    } else {
        temp->next = insert(temp->next);
    }
    return (temp);
}
```

I am trying to add node recursively but I got the error `temp was not declared`. I do not understand why I am getting this error. When I always define `temp` like this `node* temp = new node;` but now I got an error.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense for `insert` to return something. Besides, your return type is `int` but you're returning a `node*` in `return temp`. Just make the return type `void`.

Comment: @0x499602D2, `std::list`'s `insert` returns an iterator to the inserted element.

Answer (score 1):

Local variables are only visible inside the scope they're declared in, and you're declaring `temp` inside your first `if` statement. You need to move the definition outside the `if` clause:

```
int insert(node* head)
{
     node* temp=new node; // <- move to here
     if(head==NULL)
     {
          ...
     }
     else
     {
          ...
     }
     return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be multiple issues with your code:

`int insert(node* head) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        node* temp = new node;  // Newly created node will not be used at all
        if (head == NULL) {     // as head is NULL it will return 0
            cout << "Error";
            return 0;
        }
        temp->data = 20;        // Code unreachable
        temp->next = NULL;
    } else {
        temp->next = insert(temp->next); // Here you will again get an error for temp not declared
    }
    return (temp);
}`